# Dynamic programming in Lazy Racket

Tags: racket, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to remember how to do dynamic programming in lazy racket. I started wondering this after I solved one of Project Euler's problems:

> By starting at the top of the triangle below and moving to adjacent
>   numbers on the row below, the maximum total from top to bottom is 23.
>
> ```
>    3
>   7 4
>  2 4 6
> 8 5 9 3
> ```
>
> That is, 3 + 7 + 4 + 9 = 23.
>
> Find the maximum total from top to bottom of the triangle below:
>   ...

which I solved with the code below. However, I was taught about lazy racket (and indeed, programming languages in general) in school, and I seem to remember that in lazy languages, it is much easier to solve dynamic programming problems. For example, in the solutions that other eulerists have posted, one posted the haskell code he used to solve the problem, and it was barely one moe line of code than it took to actually specify the data in the problem (what was in the triangle itself). However, I didn't understand the code and so I'm still confused.

Summary:

1. How does one solve dynamic programming problems in lazy racket? As an example, answers might solve the 4-level triangle example (as opposed to the full 15-level triangle) problem as given above, or post some previously made edit distance code (that's how I learned DP).
2. Why is it easier to do dynamic programming in lazy languages (such as lazy racket)?

The 80 lines of code that I used to solve the DP problem in *regular racket* is given below.

```
#lang racket
(define (triangle-ref x y)
  (let ((triangle
       (vector-immutable
         (vector-immutable 04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23)
         (vector-immutable 63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31)
         (vector-immutable 91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48)
         (vector-immutable 70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57)
         (vector-immutable 53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14)
         (vector-immutable 41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29)
         (vector-immutable 41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33)
         (vector-immutable 99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92)
         (vector-immutable 88 02 77 73 07 63 67)
         (vector-immutable 19 01 23 75 03 34)
         (vector-immutable 20 04 82 47 65)
         (vector-immutable 18 35 87 10)
         (vector-immutable 17 47 82)
         (vector-immutable 95 64)
         (vector-immutable 75))))
    (vector-ref (vector-ref triangle y) x)))
(define triangle-size 15)
(define (problem18)
  (let ((table (let fill-table ((table (hash))
                                (current-x 0)
                                (current-y 0))
                 (cond ((>= current-y triangle-size) table)
                       ((>= current-x (- triangle-size current-y))
                        (fill-table table 0 (add1 current-y)))
                       (else (let ((reference (cons current-x current-y))
                                   (triangle-value (triangle-ref current-x
                                                                 current-y)))
                               (if (= current-y 0)
                                 (fill-table (hash-set table
                                                       reference
                                                       (cons triangle-value
                                                             empty))
                                             (add1 current-x)
                                             current-y)
                                 (let* ((left-entry (hash-ref
                                                      table
                                                      (cons
                                                        current-x
                                                        (sub1 current-y))))
                                        (left-cost (car left-entry))
                                        (left-path (cdr left-entry))
                                        (right-entry (hash-ref
                                                       table
                                                       (cons
                                                         (add1
                                                           current-x)
                                                         (sub1
                                                           current-y))))
                                        (right-cost (car right-entry))
                                        (right-path (cdr right-entry)))
                                   (if (> left-cost right-cost)
                                     (fill-table (hash-set table
                                                           reference
                                                           (cons
                                                             (+ triangle-value
                                                                left-cost)
                                                             (cons
                                                               triangle-value
                                                               left-path)))
                                                 (add1 current-x)
                                                 current-y)
                                     (fill-table (hash-set table
                                                           reference
                                                           (cons
                                                             (+ triangle-value
                                                                right-cost)
                                                             (cons
                                                               triangle-value
                                                               right-path)))
                                                 (add1 current-x)
                                                 current-y))))))))))
    (car (hash-ref table (cons 0 (sub1 triangle-size))))))
(problem18)
(provide problem18)
```

Answer (score 4):

For certain types of problems, laziness allows you to organize your solution in a nice, modular way, where you can first code as if you were generating every possible solution (even if there are infinite possibilities), and then separately write code to test whether a solution is a valid solution. In a lazy language, such an algorithm would check only enough possible solutions to compute the final result and all the other possibilities are naturally not computed so it's as efficient as more complicated strategies like backtracking.

A canonical example is an algorithm to solve a sudoku puzzle (a google search will turn up plenty of examples). You may also be interested in a paper by John Hughes called "Why Functional Programming Matters".

Having said that, in this specific case, laziness won't help much. A dynamic-programming-style solution in either an eager or lazy language will work fine (and will look approximately the same).

When solving a problem like this, it's often helpful to compute a naive solution first and then improve it. The naive solution would compute every possible total and then take the maximum. For the small triangle example, you would compute 3+7+2+8, 3+7+2+5, etc. but just writing that down reveals a possible improvement since 3+7+2 is repeated. Avoiding these kinds of repeated computations is precisely what dynamic programming does. A dynamic algorithm will calculate these intermediate results only once, and then re-use it multiple times.

We do this by incrementally computing the maximum total, one row at a time. A function to compute the maximum total in this manner might look like this:

(Note: You'll need to install the latest nightly build to run this Racket code.)

```
;; A Row is a list of at least one number.

;; A Triangle is a list of at least one Row,
;;  where each row has one more number than the previous row.

;; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; top-down solution

;; max-tri-route : Triangle -> Number
;; Computes the maximum total when moving from top of triangle to bottom.
(define/match (max-tri-route tri)
  [((list a-single-row)) 
   (apply max a-single-row)]
  [((list-rest row1 row2 rest-rows))
   (max-tri-route (cons (process-row row1 row2) rest-rows))])
```

I'm assuming a triangle is represented with a list of lists, where each sublist represents a row. We assume that the first row of the triangle represents our incrementally calculated totals. This function says that if there's only one row, then take the max of that row. Otherwise, call a process-row function with the first row (the totals so far) and the second row. The process-row function incorporates the second row into the intermediate totals and might look something like this:

```
;; process-row : Row Row -> Row
;; Takes a list of intermediate maximum values and a row, and incorporates
;;  the given row into the intermediate values.
;; - new-row always has one more element than tmp-maxes
;; - produces list of length new-row
(define/match (process-row tmp-maxes new-row)
  [((list x) (list y z)) 
   (list (+ x y) (+ x z))]
  [((list-rest x rest-maxes) (list-rest y z rest-row)) 
   (define res (process-row rest-maxes (cons z rest-row)))
   (cons (+ x y) (cons (max (+ x z) (first res)) (rest res)))])
```

This function assumes that the second given row always has one more number than the first given row. If the given two rows have only one and two numbers respectively, then just add the number from the first row to each of the numbers in the second row. Otherwise, we compute the new intermediate totals by considering three numbers at a time: one from the first given row and the two adjacent numbers from the second given row. Of course, each number in the second given row (except the ends) has two adjacent numbers from the first row so we only want to take the greater one. For example, in the little triangle example, calling process-row on the first two rows produces the intermediate values 10 and 7. Then if process-row is called with 10 7 and the next row 2 4 6, it first considers 10 with 2 and 4, producing 12 and 14. But it also has to consider 7 with the 4 below. Since 7+4=11 is less than 14, the intermediate total that we keep is the 14. The resulting intermediate totals after incorporating the third row are 12 14 13.

The solution above will efficiently produce the correct answer, even for the triangle in Problem 67. But it feels a little awkward, especially in the second part of process-row where we have to consider the overlapping cases. Let's see if we can make the solution better.

Take # 2:

In the first solution, since we process the triangle top down, our list of intermediate totals grows with each row. But then at the end we have to compute the maximum over all the intermediate values. But nothing says we have to process the triangle from the top down. Since we are only interested in the total, we would get the same answer going bottom-up. Let's see what this would look like:

```
;; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; bottom-up solution

(define (max-tri-route2 tri) (max-tri/bottom-up (reverse tri)))

;; Computes total starting from bottom row.
(define/match (max-tri/bottom-up tri)
  [((list (list the-max-total))) 
   the-max-total]
  [((list-rest row1 row2 rest-rows))
   (max-tri/bottom-up (cons (process-row/bottom-up row2 row1) rest-rows))])

;; - tmp-maxes always has one more element than new-row
;; - produces list of length new-row
(define/match (process-row/bottom-up new-row tmp-maxes)
  [((list x) (list y z))
   (list (+ x (max y z)))]
  [((list-rest x rest-row) (list-rest y z rest-maxes))
   (cons (+ x (max y z)) (process-row/bottom-up rest-row (cons z rest-maxes)))])
```

With the bottom up approach, we just have one value at the end, the final answer. Also, process-row/bottom-up is simpler than process-row since we can just directly keep the greater of the two numbers now.

However, we can do even better.

Take # 3:

This pattern of iterating over a list and accumulating intermediate values is common enough that there are built-in functions that do this: foldr and foldl. Each of these functions takes a list to traverse, an initial intermediate value, and a function that combines the next value in the list with the current intermediate value. But what's the combining function we need? It turns out that it's exactly our process-row function. Here's the solution with foldl:

```
;; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; bottom-up, with foldl

(define (max-tri-route3 tri)
  (define rev-tri (reverse tri))
  (first (foldl process-row/bottom-up (first rev-tri) (rest rev-tri))))
```

foldl starts at the left of the list, but since we want to go bottom-up, we first reverse the list. We use the first (ie bottom) row as the initial intermediate values and the rest of the rows as the triangle. When we are done, we'll have a list of one value, the answer.

Take # 4:

One final refinement. Why are we reversing the triangle, and then starting on the left. Why don't we just start on the right with foldr, using the last row as the initial accumulator? The problem with foldr is that we have to explicitly specify an initial accumulator but some languages like Haskell have a built-in function foldr1 that automatically uses the last element of the list as the initial intermediate value. Racket doesnt have it but we can easily implement it.

```
;; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; bottom-up, with foldr1

(define/match (foldr1 f lst)
  [(_ (list x)) x]
  [(_ (list-rest x rest)) (f x (foldr1 f rest))])

(define (max-tri-route4 tri) (first (foldr1 process-row/bottom-up tri)))
```

Of course, the foldr1 function assumes that the list you give it has at least one element. With the foldr1 function and using our process-row/bottom-up function from before, our solution is now a one-line function. This is probably what the Haskell solution you saw looked like as well.

For the full program with this code, see [here](https://github.com/stchang/euler/blob/master/18%2B67.rkt).